# Resources in dist not work properly in production

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have found this issues all day and finally stuck and need help, I generate my web app with `Next generate` after that I deploy to Surge, all my web is messy, it seems the CSS does not work at all and the images can't be read also, then I tried to deploy again to `GitLab` Pages, it was still the same, I don't know why though I already find the solution here all day and tried many things, can't find it at all 
is that might be tricky to fix this ??

here is my `nuxt.config.js`

```
  mode: 'universal',

  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || ''
      }
    ],
    script: [
      {
        src: 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/77777.js',
        crossorigin: 'anonymous'
      }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href:
          'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,400i,700&display=swap'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quando&display=swap'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Palanquin&display=swap'
      }
    ]
  },

  loading: { color: '#fff' },

  generate: {
   dir: 'public',
  },

  css: [
    '~/assets/css/main.css',
    '~/assets/css/input.css',
    '~/assets/css/animate.css'
  ],

  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/agile.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/model-gltf.js', mode: 'client'},
  ],

  router: {
    middleware: ['router'],
    base: '/myapp/'
  },

  buildModules: [
  ],

  modules: [
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],

  axios: {
    baseURL: "http://myapi"
  },

  build: {
    extend(config, ctx) {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code of the `nuxt.config.js` file or more.

Comment: @sugars just updated my question, take a look please

Comment: Do you have a 404 error accessing static resources? If so, try changing `base: '/myapp/'` to `base: '/'`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the mode to static

```
  mode: "static",
```

Then type `npm run build`

It should now generate an folder called "dist"

You grab everything from the folder dist and upload it on your server

Comment: I don't think so this is work, because what I see on there GitHub, that is a bug and the issue still open now